# Android - I want a hyperlink (to PDF) to open in Google Chrome instead of the PDF-app

Tags: android, google-chrome, pdf

I have a hyperlink to a PDF (within a PDF-document).
This PDF is behind a secured login.

If I click this hyperlink, Android give me some options to open the hyperlink:

- I can choose between the installed PDF-readers
- Or I can choose the standard browser

When I choose the installed PDF-reader, the program opens, but I get a download-error (because the PDF is behind a secured login).

When I choose the standard browser, I get the login page and after login the PDF starts downloading.

Is there a way to create this hyperlink that it is always (automatically) opened in the browser.
(Standard browser = chrome / All devices that have acces to the link are Android).

Answer (score 0):

> When I choose the installed PDF-reader, the program opens, but I get a download-error (because the PDF is behind a secured login)

That behavior will vary by PDF viewer.

> Standard browser = chrome

Not all devices have Chrome, and not all users wish to use Chrome.

> Is there a way to create this hyperlink that it is always (automatically) opened in the browser

You appear to be referring to a URL inside of a PDF file. If so, then no, what you want is not possible.